# Javascript not firing in dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dreamweaver

I'm learning Dreamweaver.

I have dreamweaver CC 2016, I tried to use a code in my test project.

I got the code from here:
codepen.io/KnYem/pen/JdjWxG

> I put codepen link because the question had 30000 character limit.

I use HTML and CSS codes in Dreamweaver and they work fine.
Page and styles are loaded as a reference but the issue is JavaScript.

This is the JavaScript CODE:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //on mobile - open/close primary navigation clicking/tapping the menu icon
  $('.cd-primary-nav').on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is('.cd-primary-nav')) $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('is-visible');
  });

  //upload videos if not on mobile
  uploadVideo($('.cd-hero-slider'));

  //change visible slide
  $('.cd-slider-nav li').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var selectedItem = $(this);
    if (!selectedItem.hasClass('selected')) {
      // if it's not already selected
      var selectedPosition = selectedItem.index(),
        activePosition = $('.cd-hero-slider .selected').index();
      if (activePosition < selectedPosition) {
        nextSlide($('.cd-hero-slider'), $('.cd-slider-nav'), selectedPosition);
      } else {
        prevSlide($('.cd-hero-slider'), $('.cd-slider-nav'), selectedPosition);
      }

      updateNavigationMarker(selectedPosition + 1);
    }
  });

  function nextSlide(container, pagination, n) {
    var visibleSlide = container.find('.selected'),
      navigationDot = pagination.find('.selected');

    visibleSlide.removeClass('selected from-left from-right').addClass('is-moving').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function() {
      visibleSlide.removeClass('is-moving');
    });

    container.children('li').eq(n).addClass('selected from-right').prevAll().addClass('move-left');
    navigationDot.removeClass('selected')
    pagination.find('li').eq(n).addClass('selected');

    checkVideo(visibleSlide, container, n);
  }

  function prevSlide(container, pagination, n) {
    var visibleSlide = container.find('.selected'),
      navigationDot = pagination.find('.selected');

    visibleSlide.removeClass('selected from-left from-right').addClass('is-moving').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function() {
      visibleSlide.removeClass('is-moving');
    });

    container.children('li').eq(n).addClass('selected from-left').removeClass('move-left').nextAll().removeClass('move-left');
    navigationDot.removeClass('selected');
    pagination.find('li').eq(n).addClass('selected');

    checkVideo(visibleSlide, container, n);
  }

  function uploadVideo(container) {
    container.find('.cd-bg-video-wrapper').each(function() {
      var videoWrapper = $(this);
      if (videoWrapper.is(':visible')) {
        // if visible - we are not on a mobile device 
        var videoUrl = videoWrapper.data('video'),
          video = $('<video loop><source src="' + videoUrl + '.mp4" type="video/mp4" /><source src="' + videoUrl + '.webm" type="video/webm" /></video>');
        video.appendTo(videoWrapper);
      }
    });
  }

  function checkVideo(hiddenSlide, container, n) {
    //check if a video outside the viewport is playing - if yes, pause it
    if (hiddenSlide.find('video').length > 0) hiddenSlide.find('video').get(0).pause();

    //check if the select slide contains a video element - if yes, play the video
    if (container.children('li').eq(n).find('video').length > 0) container.children('li').eq(n).find('video').get(0).play();
  }

  function updateNavigationMarker(n) {
    $('.cd-marker').removeClassPrefix('item').addClass('item-' + n);
  }

  $.fn.removeClassPrefix = function(prefix) {
    //remove all classes starting with 'prefix'
    this.each(function(i, el) {
      var classes = el.className.split(" ").filter(function(c) {
        return c.lastIndexOf(prefix, 0) !== 0;
      });
      el.className = $.trim(classes.join(" "));
    });
    return this;
  };
});
```

I tried to add script by this code:

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

The script loads in top line of dreamweaver but it doesn't work, nothing happens...

What I do wrong?

What not works: Animations and sliding doesn't happens

Comment: `the script loads in top line of dreamweaver but it doesn't works , nothing happens ...` Can you explain what you want to happen here? **And remember, Dreamweaver is not a browser!**

Comment: It sounds like you're running your code within Dreamweaver. I'd strongly recommend you don't do this. It's a fine IDE, but always test your code in an browser. Then check the console for errors

Comment: look into your dev tool if main.js is getting loaded. If not correct the path.

Comment: @PraveenKumar please check the codepen and see the result , the animations doesn't works , javascript not firing to do the animations and sliding

Comment: @SamuelHardson Okay, checking.

Comment: @SamuelHardson Clicking on the tabs, the animation works.

Comment: @PraveenKumar , it works on codepen but now in dreamweaver

Comment: @UllasHunka it's right there and loaded :(

Comment: @SamuelHardson Dude, **Dreamweaver is not a browser. It won't work!**

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm new to this stuffs and I found dreamweaver really helpful , but thanks

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not saying Dreamweaver is bad. It's great as an editor, but don't test your code in it

Comment: Yeah, exactly...

Comment: @PraveenKumar but it works when I open the github project of it . I just don't understand the difference !:\ https://github.com/CodyHouse/hero-slider it's same project but it works in dreamweaver ...!

Comment: That's weird...

Comment: It is definitely worth checking the console for errors then as that will tell you where the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the code live in Dreamweaver by pressing the **Live** button. The way you are asking this question, it seems like you are still editing the code. You need to switch it over to Live to see it in action. Whilst Dreamweaver can give you an insight to how certain aspects of the code works, it is not recommended to do this **ALL** the time. You need to check the work in progress through an actual browser, to determine what works and what doesn't.

I suggest you read the [documentation and tutorials](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/support/dreamweaver.html?promoid=SYBNM4JX&mv=other) for Dreamweaver, because while it is a very useful tool to have, you need to know how to use it correctly.